Постановка тире между словом "главное" и сказуемым
Объясните, пожалуйста, по какому правилу здесь стоит тире?
Черносмородиновый сок можно пить зимой и в другое время, главное — не хранить его более одного года.

Черносмородиновый сок можно пить зимой и в другое время, главное — не хранить его более одного года.

Главное —  прилагательное главный  использовано в значении существительного среднего рода.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка
ГЛАВНЫЙ 1. Самый важный, основной, центральный. Г-ое действующее лицо. Главное, -ого; ср. (1 зн.). Несколько слов о самом главном. Главное, в зн. вводн. сл. Разг. Что особенно важно, существенно. Г., способности иметь. Главное дело; главным делом, в зн. вводн. словосоч. Разг. =Главное. Главное дело, не нужно волноваться.

Розенталь, пункт 2

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) или если один из главных членов выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — неопределенной формой глагола: Чай пить — не дрова рубить (Посл.);
При наличии частицы НЕ тире также ставится.
